# I can not create scripting files in Umbraco installation 6.1.6

Tags: razor, umbraco

I Keep getting this error message in the Umbraco backoffice, when trying to create a scripting file.

I don't know what to do about it, can someone please help?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The method or operation is not implemented.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Source Error: 

[No relevant source lines]
Source File: MacroEngineFactory.cs    Line: 92 

Stack Trace: 

[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.]
   Umbraco.Tests.MacroEngine1.get_SupportedUIExtensions() +57
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.macro.MacroEngineFactory.GetSupportedUILanguages() in MacroEngineFactory.cs:92
   umbraco.presentation.create.DLRScripting.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in DLRScripting.ascx.cs:28
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: It looks like code that's throwing may be part of the unit test suite (from Umbraco.Tests.MacroEngine1). Are you running the compiled version of Umbraco or are you somehow running the source code directly? How did you install Umbraco, via NuGet or from a .zip archive? And lastly, has this been a running instance of Umbraco that just broke or is it a new installation?